# How to make xcodeproj file relative in Xcode 4.5

Tags: xcode, path, static-libraries, relative-path, xcode4.5

I was following [this](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/xcode/how-to-add-multiple-static-library-files-with-different-architectures-to-xcode#comments) tutorial and stumbled across this screen shot:

[image]

apparently there was a way to make the Xcode project file relative to some user defined env variable in earlier versions of Xcode (you get there by highlighting the project file then clicking <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>)

I couldn't find a way to this in Xcode 4.5 (the closest I could get to that was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10052224/766570) post, but the instructions don't work on Xcode 4.5)

ideas?

**update**: I tried the idea of changing the 'header search paths' under build settings.. and setting 'always search user paths' to 'yes' as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1416999/766570).. but then my project always builds successfully if I try that even if I put a non-existent path in that field.